# print a tensor variable

Tags: python, numpy

I have a tensor variable which is a matrix of size 4 * 5 and I was wondering if there is a quick way to print this variable to the console. Can I use *print* without a for loop to print this variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure!

```
print ("{} {} {} {}\n" * 5).format(*t)
```

The details vary depending on the exact layout of the tensor. Here I'm assuming a tuple of 20 floats.

Or if you feel really lazy:

```
print (("{} "*4 + "\n")*5).format(*t)
```

Answer (score 4):

NumPy arrays can be printed with nice formatting:

```
In [187]: arr = np.arange(4*5).reshape(4,5)

In [188]: print(arr)
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]
 [15 16 17 18 19]]
```

See [numpy.set_printoptions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) for more ways to control how NumPy arrays are displayed.

Answer (score 1):

```
def main():
    matrix = [
        [ 1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
        [13, 14, 15, 16],
        [17, 18, 19, 20],
    ]
    print("{} {} {} {} {}".format(*matrix))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4] [5, 6, 7, 8] [9, 10, 11, 12] [13, 14, 15, 16] [17, 18, 19, 20]
```